# Add babel with webpack 4 react

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs

Recently I've learned how to add babel to my webpack configuration.

I use react with typescript

I read tons of tutorial and each tutorial did different things

I used awesome-typescript-loader to load typescript. I noticed that without babel, webpack automatically transformed my code from es6 (arrow function) to es5 (which should be the responsiblity of babel).

So my question is that if I config babel, how do I know if my babel works or not?

Comment: *I noticed that without babel, webpack automatically transformed my code from es6 (arrow function) to es5* - that's very unlikely because this isn't the responsibility of Webpack. It can't transpile to ES5 itself because it's not a transpiler. Do you have TS loader enabled by chance?

Comment: yes, I used awesome-typescript-loader. I dont know why but my arrow function is transformed to function() {}.

Comment: Because TS is a transpiler. It can transpile ES6 to ES5. That's one of its features. Use either TS or Babel. You don't need them both.

Comment: Do you have any documentation showing that we just need to use one of them. There is @babel/preset-typescript, @babel/typescript. Babel has some roles here

Comment: I found a good article: https://iamturns.com/typescript-babel/

Comment: *Do you have any documentation showing that we just need to use one of them* - I don't, it just stands to reason. They solve the same task when it's about converting ES6 to ES5. That there's @babel/typescript doesn't mean that you have to use it. It's for people who are more comfortable with Babel or need it for some reasons (it supports custom transforms while TS doesn't).